# Infinite image bg

Tags: codenameone

I've set an infinite image in the theme constant. The file is in png(multiImage). However there is white bg when it is seen in the simulator and devices. If the same image is added as infinite image in new project, it works. What might be the problem here?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the `InfiniteProgress` UIID in your theme and set it to transparent in the first tab.

I'm guessing this is caused because your theme set the default behavior to be opaque instead of transparent.

Comment: Making background transparency "0" in DialogContentPane uiid works. Thanks